# Effects of turning the transaction safety OFF

Tags: sql-server, transaction, high-availability, mirroring

I am considering to turn off the transaction safety to maximize the performance.

Before that i am interested in finding the current status of transaction safety. Is there any command that we can get the status ?

I want to know the real use of turning this off. I found that it could increase performance. please let me know if there are any other advantages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189061.aspx

and also I would like to know if there are any disadvantages with turning  off the transaction safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main disadvantage of high-performance mode is going to be your possibilities of failover.  Because the communication between the principal and mirror server is now asynchronous with high-performance mode, the only way to failover is with a forced failover and **possible data loss**.

If you had to do a forced failover to the mirror server, any transactions that weren't sent to the mirror server would virtually be lost.

The real use of using high-performance mode would be that the following two conditions are true for you:

1. You want to incur the least amount of database mirroring overhead on the principal
2. You don't care if there is data loss

You should read up on the following [BOL reference on Asynchronous Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207006.aspx#Async).  It will answer all of your questions more in-depth.